# How to use/install Xperia lock-screen on any Android?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, samsung, lock-screens

I'm trying to see if there's a way (maybe an app) to change the built-in lock screen to one that either imitates or full-on emulates Sony's Xperia's lock-screen.

Forewarning: I'm not going to root my phone for this. I have enough problems with Google snooping around. Don't need malware getting more than it needs.

I understand that there are plenty of apps that include a customized lock-screen UI/design, but I specifically want the lock-screen that Xperia uses/implements.

What I don't get is if people have been able to come out with the apps that do this, what's stopping someone from porting the code or creating an app that let's the user select from different themes with regard to lock-screen design?

What I'm asking for seems to be possible by rooting my device, but I'd rather not do that.

For reference, I'm running Android Marshmallow on my Samsung S5.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some extra research (5 or so sec), I found that there's an app that gets close. It's called XZ Locker. You can get it from the [Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.app.free.studio.xperia.locker).

It has what I asked for.

**Pros:**
*Very flexible in controlling what elements show up on the screen.
*Let's you customize many aspects of the look and feel of the elements on the screen (e.g. font-size/color, swipe animation, etc.)
*Lightweight and allows for additional options some implementations don't have natively

**Cons:**
*Security isn't the best. It allows for a maximum pin number of 6 digits. If that isn't chosen, then it gives the option of a defined sequence of gestures using the common dots on the screen.
*Kind of buggy. Certain things create a weird behavior on the app, but not the representation itself (e.g. extra app instance when testing screen).
*Can be slow at times, depending on app usage and etc.